# What does the icon mean when displayed next to Microsoft Outlook login?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Does anyone know what the icon means when displayed next to Microsoft Outlook login?

[image]

I've scoured the internet but still couldn't find the answer to this one. I've even tried Google image reverse lookup, but nothing turned up.

Comment: probably one is for personal account and one is for school / company account

Comment: @SimonS I'm not sure why I can't upvote. But Thank you Simon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one on top is for personal account. 
The one at the bottom is for school/company account